# set content on stackpane instead of using visible and invisible

Tags: javafx

I am using a pane which has all the content  what I want to do is set new content ones the next button is clicked. I could use set invisible and visible for the next content but this is not what I want I want to have it in the stackpane and so I have a image stored in their and the button.

Comment: If you want to remove the current content and replace it with new content you can do this: stackPane.getChildren().remove(yourObject) and then add your new content with stackPane.getChildren().add(newObject)

Comment: do you have email or something i really need help and i am a newbie so what i have is a image and 3-4 buttons so the name of the object is on the button so when the right button is clicked then it will give points to the score else they will have to try it again so the right button give the points and move to the next question

Comment: Where is the question? Is it the image? Can you please explain what the other buttons do? Do you press a button and if the answer is correct you want to show a new image?

Comment: correct  this what i want to do the buttons should also change

Comment: Seems you might actually be asking about how to [Create wizard in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198951/create-wizard-in-javafx).

Comment: yeah sort out but the button needs to change is like a guessing game where the user needs to guess the image and press the right option with the buttons then the next pane appears with a new question with  a fresh image and the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an imageview object to your stackpane and change the image within when the button is clicked.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button("One");
        Button btn2 = new Button("Two");
        btn2.setTranslateX(btn.getTranslateX() + 60);
        Image img1 = new Image ("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Thumbs_up_font_awesome.svg/512px-Thumbs_up_font_awesome.svg.png");
        Image img2 = new Image ("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/thumbs_down.png");

        Image loadImg = new Image("http://www.ledr.com/colours/white.jpg");
        ImageView imgHolder = new ImageView(loadImg);
        imgHolder.setVisible(false);
        imgHolder.setFitHeight(100);
        imgHolder.setFitWidth(100);
        //Offset stackapane
        imgHolder.setTranslateY(-80);

        Random rand = new Random();


        btn.setOnAction(e->{
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
        imgHolder.setVisible(true);
        if(randomNum % 2 == 0){

               imgHolder.setImage(img1);
           } 
           else{
            imgHolder.setImage(img2); 
           }
        });
        //Repeat action for btn2

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn,btn2,imgHolder);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Comment: i tried using the stack pane but is not working so i just used set visible true/false any suggestion how to improve that

Comment: What exactly is not working within the stackpane? (keep in mind all element within a stackpane are centered, you have to set TranslateX and Y to change positioning of elements.) Also, ImageView cant be set to null, changing visibility accordingly is the best solution. I've updated my answer with a working example, hope that helps

Comment: it easier to show what i mean if you have a email or team-viewer i can show which would be easier basically what i have done is user a canvas which is on pane and the images/buttons are on the canvas so i set to true/false how do i change the pane to a stack pane ? shall i change the pane to stackpane ?

Comment: Could you post a sample of your code? That would give a better me understanding of what you're trying to do, the question is quite vague at the moment.

Comment: do you have an email i can send it to you as zipped files is easier please or i can give u mine what ever suits you

Comment: check your email please

Comment: you got it the email ?

Comment: yes but still dont quite understand what youre trying do to or the source of your problem

Comment: i have a lot of repetitive code so i would like to use the stackpane